# How to convert .pfx certificate to a base64 string, assuming the .pfx file have a password in Javascript and C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I want to store the certificate on S3 using C#, I think the code behind is fine since I used it many times before, however the base64 string is corrupt, I suspect the issue is on the JavaScript.

The certificate is of type  X509Certificate

in JavaScript this is the code I have:

```
var parameters = {};
var files = document.getElementById('pfx_file').files;
var binaryData1 = files[0]
parameters.file = window.btoa(binaryData1);
parameters.password = "test1212"

var zzzz= {};
var url = "";

zzzz.Upload = $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/CodeBehind.asmx/UploadCertificate",
    data: JSON.stringify(parameters)
});
```

C# code behind

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public int UploadCertificate(string file, string password)
{
    try
    {          


        byte[] pfx_bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(file);

        uploadCertificateToS3(pfx_bytes, password);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.message);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: What is `file2` in the C#? You are sending the data wrapped in a JSON object, but you've missed out the part where you deserialise the JSON data to extract that value. Is it possible that the serialization/deserialization process is causing a problem? Have you inspected the value being sent by the client, and received by the server?

Comment: @ADyson , I just edited the question, Yes I do receive the string on server side.

Comment: I wasn't questioning whether you received the string, I was interested in how you process it, and whether you've inspected its value, and compared it to what is sent by the browser. And whether you've inspected the values in JavaScript and compared the value before it's stringified in JSON, and after.

Comment: P.S. in the updated C# code above, `file2` is still undefined...

Comment: @ADyson edited it once more

Comment: Ok. And tell me, what does `file` look like in the C# when you receive it? Have you looked at it using the debugger, as I suggested? I expect it will look like a JSON object two properties, one with a base64 string and one with a password. You need to deserialize it first and extract the base64 from the object's "file" property.

Comment: Ok, I see you edited it...now there's a mismatch between your C# input parameters and the way you send the data via AJAX. If you send JSON, then the C# method must accept a single object, which is a model object containing parameters which match the JSON structure. e.g. you could make simple class for this. The C# can't accept two separate parameters like that - it has no idea how to navigate the submitted JSON string to find those values.

Comment: So your options are - 1) create a simple class to represent your submitted data structure, or 2) forget about using JSON and just send the data in standard form-url-encoded format (for that, the change should simply be: `$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    url: "/CodeBehind.asmx/UploadCertificate",
    data: parameters
});` I think)

Comment: @ADyson The parameters on UploadCertificate automatically match the values on JSON.stringify(parameters), and the certificate does get uploaded to S3, when I read it it complains. the issue is in the JavaScript because when I upload it manually I can read it successfully but when I upload it via the web page it gets stored with a different size compared to when I upload it manually which means the certificate is corrupt.

Comment: No, that isn't the issue. Read my last comments again and do some proper debugging. You are not binding the values to your c# parameters correctly, I'm pretty certain of that

Comment: The only other possibility I think is that something is wrong with your uploadCertificateToS3 method...but without seeing it no-one can tell you

Comment: P.S. if this is some new code why are you using legacy ASMX instead of WCF or Web API?

Comment: P.P.S instead of converting to base64 why don't you just upload the file directly from the web page?